# To Set a System Variable Value With JavaScript API in AutoCAD

Tags: javascript, autocad, autolisp

I'm trying to follow this guide (https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2024/ENU/?guid=adsk_jsdev_set_a_system_variable_value_to) but it is not working when i try to do it on my AutoCAD. What am I doing wrong?

- I already set the TRUSTEDDOMAINS
- I already test the async function with a alert() and the code is going in the arg.set_value line, but does not trigger the function.

Acad.SystemVariableCollection.getSystemVariable("COORDS").then(function(arg){arg.set_value(1);alert("response ok")},function(){alert("set failed!")});

I tried to set the System Variable "COORDS" from 0 to 1, but it didnt change.